# Pass UIIMage to html?

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, xcode, image

I am taking image from iphone camera using imagepickercontroller. After taking it i need to pass this image to html template. How to pass UIImage directly to html without saving in documents directory. Is there any conversion need to do to show UIImage in html.

Comment: What do you mean by "show image in html"? Is your HTML on the iPhone as well? Is it in a UIWebView?

Comment: Yes.I am having one image tag in html.My doubt is How to pass UIImage to html tag?

Comment: Rather than use the documents directory you can use the temp folder, then post it to your file if it's on a remote server, unless it's a local HTML file?

Comment: That is right.I agree with it.But i don't want to store any where.

Comment: For clear explanation.If we are having the image we will display in UIImageview right.Like that after taking image if i pass to <img>image url/or something</img> ,it wont display rght.I want to do conversion that if i can pass the image into img tag .it needs to display.

Comment: I don't see how you can do this without storing the image somewhere; the img tag expects a url or relative path to the image file in order to properly render. Am I missing something?